# scala play json No unapply or unapplySeq function found

Tags: scala, playframework

This JSON automated mapping example from the play documentation fails. why?
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.5.0"
---
import play.api.libs.json._
case class Resident(name: String, age: Int, role: Option[String])
implicit val residentWrites = Json.writes[Resident]
println(Json.toJson(Resident("john", 33, None)))
---
Error: No unapply or unapplySeq function found
      implicit val residentWrites = Json.writes[Resident]
```

Comment: For me it simply doesn't fail. I open amm repl, get dependency via `load.ivy("com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.5.0")` and paste your 4 lines of code getting `{"name":"john","age":33}`. This error usually happens when your `class` is not a `case class`, but everything is fine here.

Comment: wow, I didn't know about Ammonite! It looks great, i'll try this now

Comment: yes, it works also for me from the amm repl. :O I'll check again my project

Comment: so, it works on amm repl. however i've created a minimal sbt project and i still get the error, in the same computer (OSX 10.10.5) :O could you please checkout this project and test it? https://github.com/dportabella/test

Comment: The issue is you declare your class inside a method, I can't explain why this doesn't work but moving case class out of main method, up into the `object Test` or to a file level makes this compile.

Comment: I see, thanks. feel free to post this as an answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: FYI this can also happen if your case class has more than 22 fields. In such case, you can use following library: https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problematic code looked more or less like that:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    case class Resident(name: String, age: Int, role: Option[String])
    implicit val residentWrites = Json.writes[Resident]
    println(Json.toJson(Resident("john", 33, None)))
  }
}
```

The issue here was that this macro apparently doesn't work for classes defined inside methods. This is not a troubling limitation though as we rather don't do this sort of things.

To resolve issue class def can be moved somewhere else, like object level

```
object Test {
  case class Resident(name: String, age: Int, role: Option[String])

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val residentWrites = Json.writes[Resident]
    println(Json.toJson(Resident("john", 33, None)))
  }
}
```

or file level

```
case class Resident(name: String, age: Int, role: Option[String])

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val residentWrites = Json.writes[Resident]
    println(Json.toJson(Resident("john", 33, None)))
  }
}
```

I understand that this was only for test purposes to see minimal example, but I will still mention how we usually define classes with `Writes`.

```
object Resident {
  implicit val residentWrites = Json.writes[Resident]
}

case class Resident(name: String, age: Int, role: Option[String])
```

This way, whenever you import the `Resident`, its writes will be in the implicit scope.

Comment: the case class def was at the object level when the error first appeared. i moved it inside the method when building a minimal example to show the problem. however i didn't realize that i was getting a different type of error.

Comment: Well if you can reproduce that other error I could address that too.

Comment: thx. i found the problem, an implicit `Json.write` for a dependency was missing.

Comment: Loved the insight about the companion object :thumbs

Answer (score 10):

I got here through a google search.

For me was a `case class` that had **more than 22 attributes** that resulted in the same `No unapply or unapplySeq function found` error

Hope it helps someone else

Comment: How did you work around it?

Comment: I restructured the case classe into multiple intertwined case classes. The most important aspect was to redo the structuring of the data model

Answer (score 0):

try using jsonx

```
object Resident {
  implicit val format = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Resident]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?