# Use a custom type parameter to auto map a JSON response

Tags: json, scala, playframework, json-deserialization, jsonreader

Can I pass a custom type as a parameter in a method and use it to *read JSON* from an external API? So if I had this:

```
trait ApiInfo
case class SunInfoResults(sunrise: String, sunset: String, solar_noon: String, day_length: Long, civil_twilight_begin: String, civil_twilight_end: String, nautical_twilight_begin: String, nautical_twilight_end: String, astronomical_twilight_begin: String, astronomical_twilight_end: String)
case class SunInfo(results: SunInfoResults, status: String) extends ApiInfo
case class TvInfo(url: String, name: String, gender: String, culture: String, born: String, died: String, titles: Array[String], aliases: Array[String], father: String, mother: String, spouse: String, allegiances: Array[String], books: Array[String], povBooks: Array[String], tvSeries: Array[String], playedBy: Array[String]) extends ApiInfo
```

Before making the service call to the external API I need to declare an *implicit* to ***serialize the JSON***. So how would I designate the class that this needs to map to (using [JSON automated mapping in Play 2.5](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated))? I'm sure that this must be possible as Scala is built on the concept of reducing duplicate code - which I would otherwise have to do without such a solution. This is the line that I have had trouble passing any custom types into:

```
implicit val infoReads = Json.reads[p] // where p is SunInfo or TvInfo
```

Just to also include after doing some research on the subject of types; I am wondering if I would have to use [phantom types](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#phantom-type) as the class is not instantiated until it is correctly mapped to the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, let me know otherwise: Play can't automap `InfoReads` because its missing a Json converter for one of its property types `SunInfoResults`?

The Play JSON API provides implicit Reads/Writes for most basic types (int, boolean). To convert your own models to and from JsValues, you must define implicit Reads and Writes converters and provide them in scope. So If you are using [Automated Conversion](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) for `SunInfo` :

```
implicit val sunInfoReads: Reads[SunInfo] = Json.reads[SunInfo]
```

Play will be able to read property `results: SunInfoResults` as long as you have implicit `Reads` defined for the custom data type `SunInfoResults` within scope

```
implicit val sunInfoResultsReads: Reads[SunInfoResults] = Json.reads[SunInfoResults]
```

If I don't need to define any custom Reads/Writes or add validation, I'll often just use the formatter in the case class's companion object, which will automatically be imported into scope where `SunInfoResult` is used:

```
case class SunInfoResults(sunrise: String, sunset: String, solar_noon: String, day_length: Long, civil_twilight_begin: String, civil_twilight_end: String, nautical_twilight_begin: String, nautical_twilight_end: String, astronomical_twilight_begin: String, astronomical_twilight_end: String)

object SunInfoResults {
  implicit val sunInfoResultsFormat = Json.format[SunInfoResults]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes - `Json.reads[SunInfoResults]` needs to be implicitly declared before `Json.reads[SunInfo]` but I am still unable to pass a class reference into that implicit to avoid duplication, i.e. `Json.reads[p]` - p being SunInfo or TvInfo. As mentioned in my edit of the original question  I am now wondering if I would have to use phantom types -
 http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#phantom-type - as the class is not instantiated until it is correctly mapped to the JSON response

Comment: so the goal is to NOT have to define implicits in scope everytime you use a custom data type?

Comment: Yes - if possible!

Comment: add the reads and writes to the companion object of your case classes -- as shown in my example above and in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36952218/3384225 see the line "This way, whenever you import the Resident, its writes will be in the implicit scope."